# Hive partition scenario and how it impacts performance

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I want to ask regarding the hive partitions numbers and how they will impact performance.

let me reflect this on a real example;

I have am external table that is expecting to have around 500M rows per day from multiple sources, and it shall have 5 partition columns.

for one day, that resulted in 250 partitions and expecting to have 1 year retention that will get around 75K.. which i suppose it is a huge number as when i checked, hive can go to 10K but after that the performance is going to be bad.. (and some one told me that partitions should not exceed 1K per table).

Mainly the queries that will select from this table

50% of them shall use the exact order of partitions..
25% shall use only 1-3 partitions and not using the other 2.
25% only using 1st partition

So do you think even with 1 month retention this may work well? or only start date can be enough.. assuming normal distribution the other 4 columns ( let's say 500M/250 partitions, for which we shall have 2M row for each partition).

Comment: It's not clear what granularity the date is. If you partition by yyyy-MM, then you wouldn't get an explosion of partitions on a single day

Comment: The date mask is yyyMMdd

Comment: I need this as the data is always accessed mainly for specific day

Comment: 500M/250 ~ 2M rows per partition? How big is a row on average? You definitely don't want any single partition be anything less than HDFS block size.

Comment: Yes it is larger than the hdfs block, as i am doing insert overwrite on the the table onces all data loaded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with 3 partition columns, since that will a) exactly match ~50% of your query profiles, and b) substantially reduce (prune) the number of scanned partitions for the other 50%. At the same time, you won't be pressured to increase your Hive MetaStore (HMS) heap memory and beef up HMS backend database to work efficiently with 250 x 364 = 91,000 partitions.

Since the time a 10K limit was introduced, significant efforts have been made to improve partition-related operations in HMS. See for example JIRA [HIVE-13884](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13884.), that provides the motivation to keep that number low, and describes the way high numbers are being addressed:

> The PartitionPruner requests either all partitions or partitions based
>   on filter expression. In either scenarios, if the number of partitions
>   accessed is large there can be significant memory pressure at the HMS
>   server end.
>   ... PartitionPruner [can] first fetch the partition names (instead of
>   partition specs) and throw an exception if number of partitions
>   exceeds the configured value. Otherwise, fetch the partition specs.

Note that partition specs (mentioned above) and statistics gathered *per partition* (always recommended to have for efficient querying), is what constitutes the bulk of data HMS should store and cache for good performance.

Comment: @AmrHamza Of course this approach can be further improved if/when you have a better insight into your query patterns. For example, if most of the queries go against most recent data (let's say, one month) then you can keep last 30 days in the "online" table with all 5 partition columns, and stage old data off to "archive" table that will be partitioned by date only. You can then create a view on top of the UNION between the two tables, to provide seamless interface to the clients.

Comment: First thank you for the detailed answer. I agree with you with this archive approach.

Comment: But this will raise a question. For archived data or lets say for this huge amount of data partitioned only per day, do we have an insight or benhmark to say up to how many rows i can say i need no partition on hive? I am asking this from db background as it always will need partition to access. But for example on hive can i say for example, for more than x million rows by practice, query will be slow and so on?

Comment: I know that you mentioned that most likely this data is archived and so latency is not a factor. But i am asking this, as i want to understand what classifies a huge table practically on hive. That will force me to look for a partition to add to speed up performance.

Comment: @AmrHamza I don't think there is a number. Hive when running on MapReduce, will split processing of a file between multiple mappers based on the number of _blocks_ in that file. So by itself file size does not matter, it translates into how many mappers will (and can be) run in parallel. Partitioning provides performance boost because it allows to eliminate whole directories of files based on the search condition, not because it results in smaller files.